# Building Qt Xcode Projects From the Command Line

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, makefile

I've been playing around with Qt for a few hours now. I found that qmake produces Xcode project files on Mac OS X instead of good ol' makefiles. I don't want to launch Xcode every time I want to build "Hello, world".

How do I make qmake generate regular makefiles or, if that's something that cannot be done on the Mac, how do I compile `.xcodeproj` files from the command line?

I tried `xcodebuild -project myProject -alltargets`. I get a lot of output followed by `Abort trap`.

Comment: Looks like a bad target.  Try maybe specifying a known-good target, or just without arguments (will build the default target) and see what happens.

Comment: can state clearly how you set the QMAKESPEC variable to macx-g++ i did like QMAKESPEC=macx-g++ at terminal,but when i write the qmake command it was unable to generate a makefile for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The open-source Qt binary installers for OS X from Trolltech default to creating .xcodeproj files when you run qmake. I don't use XCode for editing so it is a pain to open it to compile the project.

To compile your projects from Terminal.app, just set an environment variable of QMAKESPEC to macx-g++

If you want to just compile a certain project from the terminal, go into that directory and run

```
qmake -spec macx-g++
```

When you run qmake, this will create a Makefile which you can use by running make.

Comment: can state clearly how you set the QMAKESPEC variable to macx-g++
i did like QMAKESPEC=macx-g++ at terminal,but when i write the qmake command it was unable to generate a makefile for me

Comment: @isaac `export QMAKESPEC=macx-g++` (if you use sh at least)

Answer (score 60):

```
$ man xcodebuild
```

So a typical command might be something like:

```
$ xcodebuild -project myProject.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

Comment: I had to write the full name of my project file to get this to work, e.g., myProject.xcodeproj

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way.  It has to work.

```
xcodebuild -project myProject.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

I have used this method in most of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this part of your back trace:

> #
>   2008-12-18 20:40:52.333 xcodebuild[1070:613] [MT] ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-921/pbxcore/FileTypes/PBXCFBundleWrapperFileType.m:174
>   #
>   Details:  path should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
>   #
>   Object:   
>   #
>   Method:   -subpathForWrapperPart:ofPath:withExtraFileProperties:
>   #
>   Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}

This implies that something, maybe one of your configuration variables, is blank when it needs to refer to a file. What I'm wondering is if maybe you have an extra target in your project that doesn't work, so that building with -alltargets is what's causing your problem.

I tested xcodebuild without any arguments on one of my projects just now - it did a default build of my project without errors. What happens if you try it without arguments?