# Issue setting QMAKESPEC environment variable

Tags: xcode, qmake

Refer to this post compile a Xcode project in command line
[Building Qt Xcode Projects From the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377992/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line)
the QMAKESPEC variable was unable to set to macx-g++.

I was doing like this in terminal `QMAKESPEC=macx-g++` but this still not able to generate a make file of my Xcode project for me.

What is the right way to setup the QMAKESPEC environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to export that variable.

Under bash:

```
export QMAKESPEC=macx-g++
```

Answer (score 0):

yes i did it, 
export QMAKESPEC=macx-g++
when i write the command $QMAKESPEC it return the result mac-g++ command not found