# compile error for iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I'm trying to compile some code for the iphone simulator but am getting this error:

```
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -Os  -O3 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -Os -x objective-c -I../../include  -c version.c      
    In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:29,
                     from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:14,
                     from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:80,
                     from version.c:11:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:166: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SecPadding’
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:196: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SecPadding’
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:228: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SecPadding’
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:257: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SecPadding’
    make: *** [version.o] Error 1
```

However, if I compile for the actual iphone, it works fine:

```
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -O3 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk  -arch armv6  -Os  -O3 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk  -arch armv6  -Os -x objective-c -I../../include  -c version.c
```

This problem happens with a file as simple as just including Foundation.h with no other code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Any ideas on what this is about?  The strange this is that I would expect this to fail for both iphone and the simulator.

*EDIT: fyi, I'm not using XCode.  This is a large, multi-platform project using Makefiles.  The commands you see above were emitted from the Makefile.*

Comment: Not that it helps in this instance, but did you know you can build an XCode project via the command line?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377992/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But yeah its not useful in this case since we're just using Makefiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw the same thing. The fix is to add a -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 compiler directive.

Comment: After some consideration (and experimenting) I think this is the better answer.  -miphoneos-version-min seems to be the iphone equivalent of -mmacosx-version-min.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean "add a -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 compiler directive"? Is it adding a new Other Linker Flag in the project settings?

Answer (score 1):

The problem only happens if you use SDK 3.0 with the iphone simulator.  Using SDK 2.0  (with gcc 4.0) will compile.  This appears to be what XCode uses by default.

Its very odd that this problem is only for the simulator and not for the iphone itself.  Also strange is that gcc4.2 won't compile with simulator sdk 2.0-- you have to use gcc4.0.

For the curious, I wrote a makefile that demonstrates the problem:

```
IPHONE_GCC_VER    = 4.0
IPHONE_SDK_VER    = 3.0
IPHONE_DEV_PATH   = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
IPHONE_SDK        = $(IPHONE_DEV_PATH)/SDKs/iPhoneOS$(IPHONE_SDK_VER).sdk 
IPHONE_GCC        = $(IPHONE_DEV_PATH)/usr/bin/gcc-$(IPHONE_GCC_VER)

SIMULATOR_GCC_VER = 4.0
SIMULATOR_SDK_VER = 2.0
SIMULATOR_DEV_PATH= /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
SIMULATOR_SDK     = $(SIMULATOR_DEV_PATH)/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator$(SIMULATOR_SDK_VER).sdk
SIMULATOR_GCC     = $(SIMULATOR_DEV_PATH)/usr/bin/gcc-$(SIMULATOR_GCC_VER)

TEST_FILE=/tmp/test.m

all: info make-test-file
    $(IPHONE_GCC)    -isysroot $(IPHONE_SDK)    -arch armv6 -c $(TEST_FILE) 
    $(SIMULATOR_GCC) -isysroot $(SIMULATOR_SDK) -arch i386  -c $(TEST_FILE) 

info:
    @echo "iphone gcc   : $(IPHONE_GCC_VER)"
    @echo "iphone sdk   : $(IPHONE_SDK_VER)"
    @echo "simulator gcc: $(SIMULATOR_GCC_VER)"
    @echo "simulator sdk: $(SIMULATOR_SDK_VER)"
    @echo ""

make-test-file:
    echo "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>" > $(TEST_FILE)
```

The defaults are the ones that work, but you can override them on the command-line.  For example:

```
$ make -f Makefile.iphone-error-demo SIMULATOR_SDK_VER=3.0 SIMULATOR_GCC_VER=4.0
iphone gcc   : 4.0
iphone sdk   : 3.0
simulator gcc: 4.0
simulator sdk: 3.0

echo "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>" > /tmp/test.m
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0    -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk     -arch armv6 -c /tmp/test.m 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -arch i386  -c /tmp/test.m 
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:29,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:14,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:80,
                 from /tmp/test.m:1:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:166: error: syntax error before ÔSecPaddingÕ
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:196: error: syntax error before ÔSecPaddingÕ
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:228: error: syntax error before ÔSecPaddingÕ
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecKey.h:257: error: syntax error before ÔSecPaddingÕ
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

or

```
$ make -f Makefile.iphone-error-demo SIMULATOR_SDK_VER=2.0 SIMULATOR_GCC_VER=4.2
iphone gcc   : 4.0
iphone sdk   : 3.0
simulator gcc: 4.2
simulator sdk: 2.0

echo "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>" > /tmp/test.m
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0    -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk     -arch armv6 -c /tmp/test.m 
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk -arch i386  -c /tmp/test.m 
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:12,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /tmp/test.m:1:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6,
                 from /tmp/test.m:1:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/usr/include/float.h:8:24: error: float.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/DriverServices.h:32,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:125,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:2,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAppleEventDescriptor.h:8,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:107,
                 from /tmp/test.m:1:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MachineExceptions.h:29:23: error: xmmintrin.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/DriverServices.h:32,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:125,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Headers/ApplicationServices.h:2,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAppleEventDescriptor.h:8,
                 from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:107,
                 from /tmp/test.m:1:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/MachineExceptions.h:216: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before Ô__m128Õ
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question. But I am seeing the very same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your settings are identical between the two projects?  I'd bet you accidentally changed some simulator settings.

Comment: Its just one project.  I'm not using XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the framework and click Get Info.  Take a look at the path in the Info dialog.  It should be short, like "System/Library/Frameworks/"

If it is not, use the Choose button to find the framework underneath the current SDK's folder.

Also, make sure just below the path you see the option "Relative to Current SDK" selected.

Comment: Right-click the framework...in the Finder?  Perhaps you mean in XCode.  fyi I'm not using XCode.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the frameworks to your project, did you set the checkbox to YES when asked if you wanted to copy the framework into the project folder. If so, the checkbox should be set to NO.

Does this also happen if you create a new project and attempt to run without adding anything, because it is possible that you've accidentally changed the compile flags in that project

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by adding this to the compiler options:

```
-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30000
```

Comment: While this doesn't seem to fix the problem for v2 of the SDK, it *does* fix it for v3.  Woot!

Comment: After some consideration (and experimenting), I think "-miphoneos-version-min" is the better answer...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when changing a project from sdk 3.2 to 4.1. Turns out the solution was changing the **iOS Deployment Target** in the build settings of my project from **2.0** to **3.0**.

Right click your project in xcode (if you're using it), build pane, iOS Deployment Target -> 3.0.

Comment: As I said in the question (and in responses to most of the answers), *I'm not using Xcode*