# Adding external scripts to Xcode4

Tags: xcode, scripting, xcode4, xcode4.2

I need to do some tasks before any Archive launched in Xcode.

**Is there any way in Xcode to add a .sh or .py script run before Archive ?**

PS : I can complete these tasks by hand but it requires time, some tasks might be forgotten or if the process is done by someone else all the tasks can be forgotten. The problem is that these tasks are required to have a successfull Apple validation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add script build phases at any point between the existing phases. [Here is a post which shows you how](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/hidden-xcode-build-debug-and-template.html). In Xcode 4 you select your project, then go to the build phases tab were you usually have the "target dependencies", "compile sources", "Link binary with libraries" and "copy bundle resources" phases, just click on "Add build phase" and select "Add run script". You can select your shell, but not script in python from there.

You can also look at [building xcode projects from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377992/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line). You could call that command line from a python script and do anything else you want from "outside" the Xcode project.