# Looking for an Xcode build script to copy files between targets

Tags: ios, xcode, build

Does anyone have a script that can copy files from one target to another, during the build process?

I have a project with one target that builds an app and another target that builds a library.  The library needs to contain a large subset of the files from the app and I want to avoid manually copying them over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the build phase of an XCode 4.x project you can add a build phase to either copy files or just run a script (that does your copying for you)

See this SO question [adding-external-scripts-to-xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168294/adding-external-scripts-to-xcode4), for additional details