# Compiling of xcode project using the command-line

Tags: xcode

I wanted to compile my xcode project using the command-line. Anyone, knows how to do this?? Or it would also be of help if you can tell me where I can find a reliable documentation / tutorial about on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377992/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

If you have an XCode project in place, you can use the `xcodebuild` command-line utility to compile it.

Failing that, you can use `gcc` / `ibtool` / *etc.* directly, and move files around to create your app bundle. That's considerably more complex, though.