# How can I use xcodebuild in command line?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm a newbie to xcode. 
I'm using xcode 4.3 with lion. I want to use xcodebuild in command line, but it report "no such file". I searched it with Finder, but no result.

What is this file's path? Does it exist in the Xcode.app? 
Can I search files in a .app package?

Additional info:
When I typed "which xcodebuild", it return /usr/bin/xcodebuild. Enter this folder, and type xocdebuild, it still return Error:

```
Can't run /Applications/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building Xcode Projects From the Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377992/building-xcode-projects-from-the-command-line)

Comment: It seem that thread cannot help me :(

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The installer put mine in

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

You can also find it in the application bundle:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
```

Comment: I find it, but still cannot work, aways report: Can't run /Applications/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).

Comment: Post *exactly* what you are typing.  Note that "/Applications/usr/bin/xcodebuild" is NOT what I wrote, and is a totally bogus location.

Comment: (I'm not saying you're messing things up, though.  It's possible that you have a broken symlink somewhere, for example.)

Comment: Spark, look carefully at what you wrote. You're leaving "Xcode.app" out of your path.

Comment: I just type "xcodebuild". It seem mac aways redirect my command to a nonsexist path "/Applications/usr/bin/xcodebuild"

Comment: But you're saying that "which xcodebuild" results in "/usr/bin/xcodebuild"?  Maybe you have a bad symlink... what do you get if you "ls -l /usr/bin/xcodebuild"?

Comment: Thanks all guys, the problem solved :) The xcodebuild in /usr/bin/xcodebuild is corrupted. I made a link from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild, it can work now.

Answer (score 16):

`/usr/bin/xcodebuild` only calls the `xcodebuild` command from the developer tools directory given by `xcode-select`. To find out the current developer tools directory as given by `xcode-select` run

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

I fixed the issue by changing that path executing

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Which is where my developer tools are. You should change `/Applications/Xcode.app` to wherever your Xcode application is.

Answer (score 0):

CHeck you have it installed. The command Line Tools for the latest XCodes are optional installs. You can install them from Xcode's preferences - Downloads Tab - Components.

Comment: I have checked it, and make sure it installed.